# Dynamically added element doesn't show w/ onChange

Tags: javascript, html, input

I already have this JavaScript code inside a function called `add()`.

```
var newinput = document.createElement('div');
newinput.innerHTML = "<br><input type='file' id='" + counter + 
"'name='filename[" + counter + 
"]' accept='image/jpeg' onchange='add()'>";
document.getElementById('asd').appendChild(newinput);
```

But instead of this innerHTML I want to do this new function:

```
var newinput = document.createElement('input');
newinput.id=x;
newinput.type="file";
newinput.name="filename";
newinput.accept="image/jpeg";
newinput.onchange=add();
```

Thus far, the new function creates an input like the innerHTML one of the first function, but doesn't add the `onchange` property (and the full created input even disapears, so I have to comment the `.onchange()`;

Is there a way I can add the ".onchange" to the createElement var or create a JavaScript listener for a couple inputs like `input.onchange() = function (){}`? 
 Thanks.

Comment: If you want to assign a function to handle onchange it'd be `newinput.onchange=add;` (no parens)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it currently is, you are expecting `add()` to return a function. Do not invoke the function and just do:

```
newinput.onchange = add;
```

```js
(function() {

  function add() {
    console.log("Added.");
  }

  function createFileInput(x) {
    var newinput = document.createElement('input');
    newinput.id = x;
    newinput.type = "file";
    newinput.name = "filename";
    newinput.accept = "image/jpeg";
    newinput.onchange = add;
    return newinput;
  }

  document.body.appendChild(createFileInput('my-input'));

})();
```

---

Here's an example of what you were doing, and how it would work:

```js
(function() {

  function add() {
    return function() {
      console.log("Added.");
    }
  }

  function createFileInput(x) {
    var newinput = document.createElement('input');
    newinput.id = x;
    newinput.type = "file";
    newinput.name = "filename";
    newinput.accept = "image/jpeg";
    newinput.onchange = add();
    return newinput;
  }

  document.body.appendChild(createFileInput('my-input'));

})();
```

Comment: I thougth for a while that it wasnt working because I didnt noticed the onchange at the html debuger, but just figured out of how it works, thanks :D